# Ideal development host operating system for QNX development

Tags: qnx

What is the ideal development host operating system for QNX development?   I have read a comment that, in order of preference, it's Linux, macOS, Windows.   As for developing on a MacBook Pro, one comment I've read is that because comparatively fewer people use macOS for QNX development the tools tend to be buggy and are behind in patches compared to tools for Linux or Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this operating system is Windows because it is the most widespread OS and Qnx Momentics works very well but you can use Momentics also under Linux or MacOS. I have been using Windows version of Qnx Momentics and don't have any problems. But one suggestion. **Don't use self-hosted version of Qnx Momentics** (Qnx Momentics installed on the target). It works very slowly.